# Start a loop at a specific index in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, indexing

Is there any way to start at an index other than zero when using a for each loop in vb?

I received an error "Input string was not in correct format" when trying:

`For Each segment As String in p`

`If not p(0) Then`

Comment: if `p` has an indexer, you want a `For ... Next` loop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [Enumerable.Skip method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) to reduce your list before iterating over it:

```
For Each segment As String in p.Skip(1)
    ...
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your misunderstanding the difference between `for each` loop and `for` loops.

`for each` will go through each element in an array
`for` will step through the indexes of an array

```
for i = 0 to p.size //change 0 to the index you want to start
    p(i)
    ...
next
```

Comment: The reason for using the for each loop is because I have another nested if statement that must read the array elements to search for a certain string..

Comment: you can do that in a for loop as well. using something like `p(i).name = "justinc535"` where name is a property.

Comment: Usually, if the lower index is `0`, the upper index will be `p.size - 1`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, is there an advantage to this? +1 btw for the explanation, I appreciate it -- some of this is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

This will skip the first element,

```
for each segment as string in p.Skip(1)
. . . .
next
```

if you want to skip the first 5 elements `. . . in p.Skip(5)`

Answer (score 1):

To get any more specific than the Skip method, you could write a lambda that only called a function passed to it under certain conditions.

The lambda would enumerate like a foreach loop, but also call a delegate passed to it as an argument to check the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `p` has indexer, like an `Array` or `IList`

```
For i As Integer = 1 To p.Count - 1
    p(i)
Next
```

This assumes you are using the standard `Option Base 0`